# Valid values of a matrix/image under a mask

Tags: image, matlab, mask

Suppose I want to extract values in an image or matrix in Matlab under a given mask (e.g., a 5x5 mask), but I want to extract only existing values because in the borders (or close to them) the mask will not find all values. I want to extract only the valid values of the image given this mask, no matter which pixel i am iterating. How to do that in Matlab?

Comment: If you are close to the border the number of values will be smaller than 25, and cannot be arranged in an array. How do you want them? Simply as a vector, with no specific order?

Comment: Yes. The values can be like a vector. No matter the order. I just want the existing/valid values in an nxn mask. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: One way to do this is by doing nxn IF statements and feeding a vector with the values. But it is so time consuming and I will use 3 mask sizes :-(

Comment: When you say extract values, do you want the mean of the pixels in your mask? Or you just want a subset of the original pixel values (cropping)

Comment: @Jigg I want the pixels inside a mask (cropping), if I am dealing with border pixels, I want only the valid pixels inside this mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to compute the x and y indices applying `max` and `min` so as not to exceed the image boundaries:

```
img = magic(7); %// define example image
Nx = 5; %// block size in x
Ny = 5; %// block size in y
x = 2; %// pixel x
y = 6; %// pixel y

nx = (Nx-1)/2;
ny = (Ny-1)/2;
xx = max(x-nx,1):min(x+nx,size(img,1));
yy = max(y-ny,1):min(y+ny,size(img,2));
block = img(xx, yy);
```

Example result:

```
>> img
img =
    30    39    48     1    10    19    28
    38    47     7     9    18    27    29
    46     6     8    17    26    35    37
     5    14    16    25    34    36    45
    13    15    24    33    42    44     4
    21    23    32    41    43     3    12
    22    31    40    49     2    11    20

>> block
block =
     1    10    19    28
     9    18    27    29
    17    26    35    37
    25    34    36    45
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion and give you a feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can use the function `blockproc` to define your own neighborhood-based operation.

```
M=5; N=5;
fun = @(block_struct) block_struct.data;
B = blockproc(I,[M N],fun, 'TrimBorder', 1);
```

where `I` is your image (matrix). Then change `fun` to whatever you need. The `TrimBorder` parameter should cope with your border issue.

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem is the 'TrimBorder' parameter, it trims off border pixels.I want the border pixels, but only the valid ones inside the mask.Thanks anyway.